# Display a UILabel over AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayerViewController and want to display a UILabel over the player, but I cannot get the UILabel to appear. This used to work fine when I used an MPMoviePlayerViewController, but since switching to the AVPlayerViewController, it no longer works.

I am launching the AVPlayer like this:

```
        AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:theURL];
        AVPlayerViewController *theMovie = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:theMovie animated:YES completion:nil];
        theMovie.player = player;
        [player play];
```

The UILabel is defined as lblOverlayView and is setup like this:

```
        lblOverlayView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        lblOverlayView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 60);
        lblOverlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblOverlayView.alpha = 0.5f;
        NSString *combinedString1 = [@"Now Playing" stringByAppendingString:@" "];
        NSString *combinedString2= [combinedString1 stringByAppendingString:@"Podcasts"];
        lblOverlayView.text =combinedString2;
        lblOverlayView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        lblOverlayView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lblOverlayView.numberOfLines = 0;
        lblOverlayView.font =[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        lblOverlayView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin);
        [theMovie.view addSubview:lblOverlayView];
        [theMovie.view bringSubviewToFront:lblOverlayView];
```

How do I get the UILabel to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the controller's `.contentOverlayView`:

```
//[theMovie.view addSubview:lblOverlayView];
//[theMovie.view bringSubviewToFront:lblOverlayView];

[theMovie.contentOverlayView addSubview:lblOverlayView];
```